# Cypress 13 Cognito Login - An error was encountered with the requested page

Tags: cypress, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to log into my web-hosted application using Cypress (13.6.3) which uses an AWS Cognito app client (default settings) and hosted UI for authentication, but when I try to log in I'm able to successfully type the username/password and click submit, but once the form submits I encounter this incredibly unhelpful message:

"An error was encountered with the requested page."
[image: An error was encountered with the requested page.]

This is very specifically a Cypress issue as when I do the same steps using a browser (or using Selenium) I don't encounter this problem.  I've followed [this guidance from Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/amazon-cognito-authentication#Login-with-cyorigin) on logging in using cy.origin() and what's frustrating is it looks like Cypress is working up to the point the login occurs. The test fails after this because it hasn't redirected back from the origin location (which is a logical fail as it's showing the Cognito /error page).

I've got the Cognito app client set up so its scope includes openid and it has implicit and authorisation code grants enabled.

**I was wondering if anyone had encountered an issue like this or had any pointers on how I might be able to resolve this problem?**  I've checked the logging within my application but there's no error because Cognito seemingly doesn't pass the user back to the callback uri provided when navigating there.  AWS Cognito doesn't seem to provide any useful logging via CloudWatch or CloudTrail either to indicate why it may have failed.

Here's the code I'm using to log in for reference (this has been simplified, user details and the urls aren't hard-coded as they are here, it's just for demo purposes):

```
cy.visit(Cypress.env('url') + '/loggedOut') # Sets base URL so cy.origin works as expected
cy.visit(Cypress.env('url') + '/logIn')  # Automatically redirects to Cognito 

cy.origin(
  'https://<project-name>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com',
  {
    args: {
            username: 'testUser',
            password: 'testPassword',
          },
  },
  ({ username, password }) => {
    cy.get('input[name="username"]:visible').type(username)
    cy.get('input[name="password"]:visible').type(password, {log: false,})
    cy.get('input[name="signInSubmitButton"]:visible').click()

    cy.wait(2000)
  }
)
```